# public address variable causes BadFunctionCall exception

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, python, web3.py

See the contracts at the bottom. You will notice that the contracts are identical, except that the first contract's *authority* field is marked public, while the second isn't.

The second contract works fine. I can call hash(), test(), whatever, and everything works as expected.

However, nothing works with the first contract. I can use neither call() nor transact() on any function (although estimateGas() works fine). Instead, I get the following error:

> eth_abi.exceptions.InsufficientDataBytes: Tried to read 32 bytes.  Only got 0 bytes
>
> web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?

I'm not sure what the problem is, can anyone enlighten me? Here are the contracts:

```
contract Award {
    
    address public authority;
    string public hash;
    
    bool itWorked = false;
    
    mapping(address => bool) users;
    
    function Award(string _hash) public {
        authority = msg.sender;
        hash = _hash;
    }
    
    function addUser(address _address) public {
        users[_address] = true;
    }
    
    function deleteUser(address _address) public {
        users[_address] = false;
    }
    
    function hasUser(address _address) public view returns (bool) {
        return users[_address];
    }

    function test() public pure returns (bool) {
        return true;
    }
    
}
```

and

```
contract Award {
    
    address authority;
    string public hash;
    
    bool itWorked = false;
    
    mapping(address => bool) users;
    
    function Award(string _hash) public {
        authority = msg.sender;
        hash = _hash;
    }
    
    function addUser(address _address) public {
        users[_address] = true;
    }
    
    function deleteUser(address _address) public {
        users[_address] = false;
    }
    
    function hasUser(address _address) public view returns (bool) {
        return users[_address];
    }

    function test() public pure returns (bool) {
        return true;
    }
    
}
```

---

As requested, here is the Python code making the call:

```
contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=contract.abi, bytecode=contract.bytecode)
hash = contract.constructor('test_hash').transact(transaction={'from': self.account, 'gas': 410000})

while True:
        receipt = e.get_transaction_receipt(hash)

        if receipt:
            break

        sleep(2)

address = w3.w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash)['contractAddress']

instance = w3.eth.contract(abi=contract.abi, address=address)

instance.functions.test().call()
```

Comment: Hard to say like that. Could you provide your js code? Are you sure you have the correct ABI?

Comment: It's definitely the correct ABI, I have tested with both contracts countless times. I'm actually using web3.py, but yeah I'll post the code now!

Comment: Check the status code in the transaction receipt before extracting the contract address. `0` means there was a deployment failure.

Comment: @carver Unfortunately it's a private network and I never enabled Byzantium when I started it. I have checked the transaction though and everything seems to be OK. I don't understand why it would be any different to the one without "public".

Comment: @carver I enabled Byzantium on the network, and the status flag is 0 when I use the bad contract. Any ideas why this might be? Remix IDE isn't saying there's anything wrong with the contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't provide enough gas for the contract constructor to execute.

As suggested in the comments, I checked the transaction status, which was 0. I then realized the gasUsed was equal to the gas provided.

After increasing the gas for the deployment transaction, the contract ran fine.